# How to change the background color of a GridView row on row item value change?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, gridview, data-binding

I have a gridview within a listview as below to show a readonly table of a class object (I get that object from the network):

```xml
<ListView DataContext="{DynamicResource appModel}" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CurrentData, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource DataConverter}}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Item1}"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Item2}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View
</ListView>
```

The data populates correctly in the listview/gridview when I update the binded property `CurrentData` in the object `appModel`.

Now I need to update row/cell's background color when some row cell changes it's value to a new value (different from previous). How do I go about doing this?

Comment: You can use `DataTrigger` for that

Comment: The behavior is unclear. Should the color be changed on each update to the new one white->red->yellow->blue? Should the color be changed once and stay so white->red?

Comment: @Rekshino Like  red when previous != current, white if previous = current for each row.

Comment: It will be hard to implement this when you reset the ItemsSource, since the old items are simply lost then. Better bind to a collection of items that are overwritten on each update. The item class could then have a `HasChanged` property that is set in your view model. Then implement a DataTrigger on that property.

Comment: @themagicalyang You mean, that if the cell/row is red from previos update, then it becomes white on new update with no changes(relative to the last  update)?

Comment: @Rekshino Yes. I was able to do it DataTriggers and as Clemens suggested.